# Converting ArcGIS point shapefile to Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, illustrator

I have 60000 points .shp file and I want correctly convert them into .AI.
I want to receive the simple circles, but when converting I can get only:

1. polygon with a number of points which when zooming looks clumsily - when selected "Convert Marker Symbols to Polygons" export option.
2. font units(ESRI Default Marker) - when unselected "Convert Marker Symbols to Polygons"

Is it possible to automatically replace all those objects in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am uding osm extract file of points of interest for india having 82,000 points all credits to osm mapping communtiy. if your pc specs are low skip to image or split up your shapefile into parts.

Please follow this step only if you have autocad map

If you do not have Autocad map please jump to 
Image 7 to directly export your shapefile to cad format
[image: FIRT IMAGE]

1. Click on map setup menu.
2. Click on Assign button to open the cordinate system list.

[image: Second image]
1. Type crs for gcs 1984 or else type the coordinate system your shapefile is in.
2. Check the coordinate system of your shapefile refer to the images given below.

[image: third image]
1. Right click here to open layer menu.
2. Click on properties to see layer properties.

[image: fourth image]
In my case it is Wgs 1984 which is 4236   one can always get this code by a simple google search for any coordiante system.

[image: fifth image]
1. Click on Connect button in feature data to open the dialog box to add spatial data.
2. Click on the Shp button to add a shapefile to the list of sources.
3. Select Add SHP Connection.

[image: sixsth]
1. Browse to the shapfile in the dialog box.
2. Click on open.
3. Click on connect button.
4. Click on Add to map button that will appear after clicking on connect button.

[image: seventh image]
1. If you dont have Autocad Map then you can simply export it to a dwg file.
2. Then go ahead and open the dwg file.

[image: eigth image]
1. After opening the exported cad file or importing shapefile to cad 
2 .Please select all the points

[image: ninth image]
1. After selecting all the points.
2. Type DDPTYPE in the command menu.
3. Select circle option or any other marker you want to use.
4. Enter value in points you want your cicle to be 
5. select absolute value to fix the size of circle.
6. and click on ok to apply it.

[image: tenth image]
all the points are now convereted to circles you may need to adjust your point size value to prevent overlaps.

[image: eleventh image]
Copy these points By selecting and pressing CTRL + C

[image: twelveth image]
Paste into illustrator using Ctrl + V

[image: thirteenth image]
Ungroup by 
1. Right click on points
2. Click on ungroup option

[image: fourteenth image]
Tada your file is ready

things to take care of 
1. Circle may not appear circle at higher zoom levels
2.  For that adjust your rendering settings in preferences.

Comment: Can you mark my answer correct as it would have help you out i assume.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert polygon to centroid point then export as AI from Arc map or EPS. You can also try DXF.

Comment: We're looking for detailed answers, using several paragraphs and screenshots. This is more of a comment than an answer.